# Show current progress in Help Center > Badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

It would be very nice if users could see their current progress related to particular badges. For example:

```
Deputy - Raised 80 helpful flags
```

would be rendered in the following way:

```
Deputy - Raised 80 helpful flags (23/80)
```

Comment: Badges are mostly meant to be a nice surprise, and some require complicated (expensive) SQL queries to verify. I doubt this will be added.

Comment: If it's very expensive then maybe adding such information just on particular badge page (like Help Center > Badges > Deputy) would be better solution - not so fancy but still useful :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters caching can solve this. :)

Comment: Complicated queries can have progress refreshed once every 24 hours, this is enough for information.